# How to get matched array object based on their values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to get the array object based on values in javascript.
I have array object `obj1, obj2` , how to get the object if name of obj1 matches with obj2 values in javascript

```
var obj1=[
  {name: "country", value: "countries"},
  {name: "city", value: "cities"}
]
var obj2=[
  {countries:"countries"},
  {sample: "sample"}
]
var result = this.getMatchedObj(obj1, obj2);

function getMatchedObj(obj){
    const newlist = obj1.map((elem) => obj2.find(e=>Object.values(e)===elem.value));
    return newlist;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
 {name: "country", value: "countries"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   var obj1=[
  {name: "country", value: "countries"},
  {name: "city", value: "cities"}
]
var obj2=[
  {countries:"countries"},
  {sample: "sample"}
]
let data = obj1.filter(ele=>obj2.findIndex(el=> Object.values(el)[0] ==ele.value)!=-1)
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
var obj1=[
  {name: "country", value: "countries"},
  {name: "city", value: "cities"}
]
var obj2=[
  {countries:"countries"},
  {sample: "sample"}
]

function getMatchedObj(obj1, obj2){
    const values = obj2.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(Object.values(cur)),[]);
    const newlist = obj1.filter(({value}) => values.includes(value));
    return newlist;
}
const result = getMatchedObj(obj1, obj2);
console.log(result);
```

Here's a playground:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6tmjcc

Answer (score 0):

You can can with this:

```js
var obj1=[
  {name: "country", value: "countries"},
  {name: "city", value: "cities"}
];
var obj2=[
  {countries:"countries"},
  {sample: "sample"}
];

var item = obj1.find(item => obj2.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]).indexOf(item.value) > -1);

console.log(item);
```

Get all of the object property values from `obj2` to an array. Then making an array to check existing with `obj1`

---

Or using *for* loop:

```js
var obj1=[
  {name: "country", value: "countries"},
  {name: "city", value: "cities"}
];
var obj2=[
  {countries:"countries"},
  {sample: "sample"}
];

for (var obj of obj2) {
  var values = Object.values(obj);
  
  var item = obj1.find(item => values.indexOf(item.value) > -1);
  
  if (item) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`, `find` and `includes` methods.
If you just need one object, Then change `filter` call to `find`.

```js
const getMatchedObj = (obj1, obj2) =>
  obj1.filter(({ value }) =>
    obj2.find((obj) => Object.values(obj).includes(value))
  );

var obj1 = [
  { name: "country", value: "countries" },
  { name: "city", value: "cities" },
];
var obj2 = [{ countries: "countries" }, { sample: "sample" }];

console.log(getMatchedObj(obj1, obj2));
```